# FastAPI normal request returning auth error without setting it

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I have this normal request on my fastAPI application

```
@router.get("/followers", summary="Get Followers")
async def get_Followers() -> Any:
    return {"full_name": "John Doe"}
```

the error is when i tried it on postman i got that error

```
{
    "detail": "Not authenticated"
}
```

after that i tried to change **`/followers`** to **`/get-followers/`**
the api worked well and returned the wanted result

```
{
    "full_name": "John Doe"
}
```

i cant understand where is the problem and why i got that error can i get help,
**Note** that i dont use any cache method

Comment: Do you have any other routes starting with `followers`? There is not enough information in your question for anyone to say anything useful, so you'll have to add more details.

Comment: hey @MatsLindh well i dont have any other routes starting with `followers`, i have a normal fastAPI application with basics, but now when i change the route to `@router.get("/followers/")` after adding **`/`** its works normal.

Comment: @Chris ,  im using a normal fastAPI application, without any auth protection, i removed it but looks like the route has caches with the old route and not accepting the new modifications